# How to use Data Annotations on the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-annotations, silverlight-5.0

I'm using RIA Services with LinqToEntitiesDomainService<> and Silverlight 5 Beta to generate the DomainContext code on the client side.  I have Data Annotations in my Models/Entities to do basic validations, and when using the Models directly, controls such as DataForm perform validations out-of-the-box.  But I'm wrapping my Model in a ViewModel, so I lose all of that automatic validation.  Here is a simplified example:

```
// In DataModel assembly, regenerated on the client side by RIA Services 
public class PetModel 
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Only on the client side
public class PetViewmodel
{
    private PetModel _model;

    public PetViewmodel(PetModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _model.Name; }
        set { _model.Name = value; }
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I ensure that `Name` is considered `Required` on the client side without duplicating all of my annotations in the ViewModel?   (I may have to use these Entities with different ViewModels in the future - and I'd like to keep the same annotations)

I thought of manually adding the `MetadataType` attribute to the ViewModel, pointing to the Model type:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PetModel))]  
public class PetViewmodel
{
...
}
```

But alas, `MetadataTypeAttribute` is not available in the Silverlight 5 version of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

Edit: Clarification - the metadata for my entities is included in the entities with a nested class.  I code this class manually because my L2E model is in a separate assembly so the DomainService wizard would not generate it for me.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Metadata))]  
public partial class PetModel 
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public class Metadata 
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This should be exactly how the wizard would generate the metadata if I understand it correctly.  The RIA Services code generator generates the right data annotations in the client code, so it's picking it up correctly.

Comment: Didn't a .meta.cs file get generated with your domain service?

Comment: @subt13: Thanks for the response.  I added a clarification that answers your question.  You've given me an idea: I think if I separate out my MetaData classes and share them between client and server, I should be able to include them on the client by using partial classes instead of MetadataTypeAttribute.  We'll see...

Comment: Good thanks, I have the same setup as you, but I tried to inherit from DomainService instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this.  In hopes that it will help someone in the future:

I used a base class for the viewmodel that performs validations.  On that base class I implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo`, and I override the `NotifyOfPropertyChange` method (This is part of [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), but if you're not using you could just as easily attach to the `PropertyChanged` event for the model).  In the event handler, I perform validation on that property.  In the validation code, I use reflection to find the property of the same name, and any validation attributes on the property (`RequiredAttribute`, `RangeAttribute`, etc).  Then I use the values from these properties to validate the new value on the changed property, creating `ValidationResult` objects and adding them to a `List<ValidationResult>`.  If all of the 'local' validations pass, then I proceed to perform 'remote' validations (i.e. Validations that require interaction with the server, such as checking for uniqueness).

It was a lot of work, but unfortunately this - or something similar - is necessary.   All of the MS examples appear to not use the MVVM. I thought this was just to keep them short/simple, but the Silverlight team at MS appears not to have given serious consideration MVVM when designing the object model.

Comment: The code is huge.  Not going to post 50 pages of code, sorry.